# Parse excel in python as a dictionary

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have an excel spreadsheet which looks like below:

```
    z1          z2           z3
a   [2,7,14]    [2,7,14]    [3,4]
b   4           8            7
c   5           7            5
d   10          10           10
```

I tried to parse it as a dictionary in python using the below code and my parsed dict looks like below:

```
file_path = 'b.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding='utf-16')
df.to_dict()


{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'},
 'z1': {0: '[2,7,14]', 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 10},
 'z2': {0: '[2,7,14]', 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 10},
 'z3': {0: '[3,4]', 1: 7, 2: 5, 3: 10}}
```

Though I want my parsed result as below:

```
{'z1': {a: '[2,7,14]', b: 4, c: 5, d: 10},
 'z2': {a: '[2,7,14]', b: 8, c: 7, d: 10},
 'z3': {a: '[3,4]', b: 7, 2: c, d: 10}}
```

I have the flexibility to change my excel spreadsheet to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A small change in your code, you need to set your first column as index, for that you need to add this line

```
df = df.set_index(list(df)[0])
```

> If first column has a name then you can use

```
df = df.set_index('column name')
```

> Final code will be like this

```
file_path = 'b.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding='utf-16')

df = df.set_index(list(df)[0])
df.to_dict()
```